# Getting data from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have data in a S3 bucket, that is filling up day by day (data from a certain log). The bucket has different files which i read and then put in as one csv, but it is  very slow to read the bucket each time.

For example:

bucketxyz: file1, file2, file3
I read the contents of file1 and extract data from this file1 into a csv then i continue with file2 and do the same and append some data from file2 to the a csv file. File 1 and File 2 are not deleted, but stay in the bucket.
After one week, i need to do a new report using the same bucket. But now there are new files and i would reread the old ones again. So I read the whole bucket again and save it.
The resulting CSV, i put into another bucket.

What would be a efficient way to read the data from the bucket? Should i have a separate job, which puts the bucket data in a database and then read from the database?

Comment: Can  you provide any info about your use-case?  The size of  the files, number of them, format, what do you do now, and why exactly it does  not work?

Comment: Please **Edit your question** to provide more details. For example: What do you mean by "read the bucket"? Do you mean "listing the bucket", or are you somehow using all of the CSV files (if so, how are you using the CSV files)? Are you wanting to query all of the CSV files at the same time?

Comment: I edited my question @John Rotenstein

Comment: Your question is still a little difficult to understand. Are you saying that new CSV files appear in your bucket each day? Are they coming from you, customers, or systems? And you want to combine these files into a single CSV file? What do you mean by "put _some_ data from it" -- are you combining ALL rows, or are you doing some logic to include only _some_ rows? What do you do with the resulting CSV -- do you put it back into the bucket? Do you delete the original files the were used? Or are you keeping every file in the bucket and re-combining them again each day? More information please!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I updated my question.

Comment: When you read the contents of multiple files "into a csv", where do you store the 'resulting' CSV? Is it always in a different bucket? Instead, you could store that CSV in the same bucket as the original files, and then **delete the original files** since the data is already in the combined file. This would greatly reduce the number of CSV files. How big is each individual 'incoming' CSV file and how many arrive each day? One possibility is to **use Amazon Athena to query data across all CSV files simultaneously**, but you haven't told us how you use the 'resulting' CSV information.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Result is put into another bucket, but putting it into the same bucket and deleting it seems a good idea, thanks

Comment: That would reduce the number of CSV files, which makes things simpler. Depending on what you are doing with the resulting CSV file, you could use Amazon Athena to query the CSV files in S3, treating them a bit like a database.